# html5 elements confusion

Tags: html

I'm slowly making the transition from XHTML1.1 to HTML5 but I'm having trouble getting my head around the new elements and when they should be used. Obviously `<header>`, `<nav>`, `<footer>` & `<article>` are self explanatory but `<section>`, `<aside>` are slightly confusing.

a document might look like this:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
  <header>...</header>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <!-- What about the content? -->
</div>
```

So below the `<nav>` you would have the content section, would this be `<div>` or `<section>` and why isn't there a `<content>` tag?

My next issue is with a sidebar, after research I found that `<aside>` shouldn't be used for a sidebar, but I also read that recently the specification has been updated to include `<aside>` for sidebars if outside of the `<article>` tag. So again why isn't there a sidebar element.

My confusion spans from the presence of `<header>`, `<nav>`, `<footer>`. Almost every website I have ever made contains 5 sections; Header, Nav, Content, Sidebar & Footer so why is there only specific elements for 3 of these?

Hope you can clear things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a sidebar is in the realm of presentation(css); so it was not included in the html5 specification.